# any way to call external c dll function in rust?

Tags: rust, dll, ffi

question:

- dll is not registered (non-system dll) and not allowed to register.
- dll can be put in every non-system path you like, e.g. %appdata% or project folder.
- dll depends on other non-system dlls, which are placed in a same folder.
- dll can be packed into program, without dynamic loading.

I have tried libloading, rust-bindgen, dlopen2. None of them has solved error code 126, which means dll dependencies not found.

- is there anyway to add dll dependencies in cargo.toml to pack dll into program to load?
- is there anyway to load dll with dependencies?
- shall I use extern "C" or extern "stdcall" or others?

Comment: _Should I use `extern "C"` or `extern "stdcall"` or others?_ → that depends on your DLL

Comment: _Is there anyway to add DLL dependencies in `Cargo.toml` to pack DLL into program to load?_ → no, `cargo` is just a build tool. Packing DLL and other files with binaries for distribution is the role of a package manager.

Comment: _Is there anyway to load dll with dependencies?_ → yes, `bindgen` or `libloading` can do it. Assuming you're on Windows, just put the DLL with all its dependencies in the same folder as the executable.